# Complexity of BigO notation

Tags: java, big-o

I've been doing some questions but answers not provided so I was wondering if my answers are correct

a) given that a[i....j] is an integer array with n elements and x is an integer

```
int front, back;

while(i <= j) {

    front = (i + j) / 3; 
    back = 2 * (i + j) / 3;

    if(a[front] == x)
        return front;
    if (a[back] ==x)
        return back;

    if(x < a[front])
        j = front - 1;
    else if(x > a[back])
        i = back+1;
    else {
        j = back-1;
        i = front + 1;
    }
}
```

My answer would be O(1) but I have a feeling I'm wrong.

B)

```
public static void whatIs(int n) {
    if (n > 0)
        System.out.print(n+" "+whatIs(n/2)+" "+whatIs(n/2));
}
```

ans: I'm not sure whether is it log4n or logn since recursion happens twice.

Answer (score 4):

A)  Yes.  `O(1)` is wrong.  You are going around the loop a number of times that depends on `i`, `j`, `x` ... and the contents of the array.  Work out how many times you go around the loop in the *best* and *worst* cases.

B)  Simplify `log(4*n)` using `log(a*b) -> log(a) + log(b)` (basic high-school mathematics) and then apply the definition of big O.

But that isn't the right answer either.  Once again, you should go back to first principles and count the number of times that the method gets called for a given value of the parameter `n`.  And do a proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are incorrect.

In the first example on each iteration either you find the number or you shrink the length of the interval by 1/3. I.e. if the length used to be n you make it (2/3)*n. Worst case you find x on the last iteration - when the length of the interval is 1. So just like with binary search the complexity is calculated via a log: the complexity is O(log<sub>3/2</sub>(n)) and this in fact is simply O(log(n))

In the second example for a given number n you perform twice the number of operations needed for n/2. Start from n = 0 and n = 1 and use induction to prove the complexity is in fact O(n).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A) This algorithm seems similar to the [Golden section search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search). When analyzing complexity, it's sometimes easier to imagine what would happen if we would *extend* the data structure, rather than contracting it. Think of it like this: Every loop removes a third from the search interval. That means, that if we know exactly how long time it takes for a certain length, we could add 50% more if we're allowed to loop once more – an exponential growth. Thus, the search algorithm must have complexity O(log *n*).

B) Every time we add a "layer" of function calls, we need to double the number of them (since the function always calls itself twice). In other words, given a certain length and time consumption, doubling *n* also requires twice as many function calls in the last layer. The algorithm is O(*n*).

Comment: @StephenC Yeah, thanks for pointing it out. I was looking too much at the question. I believe the reasoning was sound, though, but it should be *n* instead of 1.